# UIActionSheet missing background in iOS7

Tags: ios, uiactionsheet, ios7

EDIT: This is intended behavior, but that was not obvious from the UI Transition Guide from Apple. I found a much better example here: http://iosandmacbuddy.wordpress.com/2013/07/30/ios-7/

In iOS7, the background has disappeared from my UIActionSheet. I know the UIActionSheetStyle constants are no longer used, but I wasn't using them before! In the [UI Transition Guide](http://www.slideshare.net/evgenybelyaev16/transition-guide) (Page 45), the sample appears like this:

[image]

Mine, however appears without the grey background box, instead appearing as floating buttons with no background:

[image]

Am I misunderstanding and the grey box on the guide is the view behind the UIActionSheet? (and therefore my behavior is expected)

Comment: This seems correct with the new iOS 7 UI.

Comment: Sorry, my image didn't link correctly. The one seen is what it should look like from the UI transition guide. I'll try to get my image fixed.

Comment: Fixed my image (with some parts blocked out of course). Am I misunderstanding and the grey box on the guide is the view behind the UIActionSheet? (and therefore my behavior is expected)

Comment: No this seems correct to me too.

Comment: Ok, fair enough, just doesn't look very intuitive in our application. Guess I'll be making a custom action sheet.

Repost as an answer and I'll mark it correct, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly there is nothing wrong with that.

It looks perfectly fine to me.